# What is the difference between a non-awaited Task.Run and Task.RunSynchronously

Tags: c#, .net

They seem to be identical to me, is there a difference between these two lines of code?

```
new Task(myMethod).RunSynchronously();
// and
Task.Run(() => myMethod());
```

Comment: did you check the difference reading [C# MSDN RunSynchrononously](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321435(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MethodMan I thought that Task.Run executes synchronously when it isn't awaited, am I wrong in thinking that?

Comment: did you read the documentation..? I provided you the MSDN link I would suggest you read both and understand the difference..

Comment: @MethodMan Okay, Task.Run executes on a different thread, but there's no other difference? Both methods seem to perform the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can see the difference in documentation:

`Task.Run(() => myMethod());`

> Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool and returns a Task object that represents that work.

`new Task(myMethod).RunSynchronously();`

> Runs the Task synchronously on the current TaskScheduler.

Hence, they are not identical anymore.